# Array Aggregation - Retrieving an entire row of data in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

We have used array aggregation method  and loaded the data in BigQuery

Clarification :

[image]

> Is it possible to retrieve the specific value in array aggregation method? What are the methods available for retrieving the data from the field which have multiple records?

Query Clarification

> We tried to find out the value of all data from the particular field which has multiple values in the screenshots [image.png] using below query but we got an error.

Sample Query

```
select fv,product.productSKU,product.productVariant,product.productBrand 

from dataset.tablename 
where hn=9 and product.productBrand='Politix'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use UNNEST as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  fv,
  product.productSKU,
  product.productVariant,
  product.productBrand 
FROM `dataset.tablename`,
  UNNEST(product) product
WHERE hn=9 
AND product.productBrand='Politix'
```

You can also check [Working with Arrays in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays)